# In ngx-editor how to insert html block at cursor placement when clicked on a button

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ngx-editor

I am using ngx-editor in Angular 7. I need to insert the html at the position of the cursor on click of the params from the parameters list. Attached is the image of my current view. Right now on click of parameter, it is appending it in this way as shown in the picture. [image: Right now on click of parameter, it is appending it in this way as shown in the picture.]

I want each selected parameter to be separate badge, which should be deleted in single backspace. Also you should be able to write plain text as well.

This is how I am doing right now.

```
   <div class="bm-link-btn pull-right mt-10" [tooltip]="tooltipTemplate" placement="bottom" > 
    Parameters </div>

   <ng-template #tooltipTemplate>
       <div class="u-display-flex text-left">
           <div class="p20" *ngFor="let item of paramsList$|async as params">
              {{item?.category}}
              <div class="bm-link-btn" *ngFor="let param of item.parameters">
                 <span (click)="onClickOfParams(param.value)">{{param.displayName}} 
                 </span>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </ng-template>




 onClickOfParams(value) {
     document.getElementById('ngx-editor-textarea').focus();
     let html = `
          <div class="parameter-item"><div class="badge-plain-new">`+ value + `</div></div>`;

    if (!document.execCommand("InsertInputText", false, '')) {
      document.execCommand("InsertHTML", false, html);
    }
 }
```

This is what I want to achieve. Can anyone tell a better way of doing this?

[image]

Comment: ngx-editor is discontinued. Check our fork: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@iget/editor

Answer (score 0):

HTML CODE:-->

```html
<div class="field">
  <label>Email Body</label>
  <app-ngx-editor id="EmailBody" height="300px" minHeight="50px" 
    [spellcheck]="true" formControlName="EmailBody" #EmailBody>
  </app-ngx-editor>
  <span class="text-holder text-danger">
    {{addNotificationTemplateFormErrors.EmailBody}}
  </span>
</div>
```

Component:-->

```
@ViewChild('EmailBody') EmailBody: ElementRef;

this.cursorPositionedField = this.EmailBody;
if (this.addNotificationTemplateForm.value.EmailBody != null 
  && this.addNotificationTemplateForm.value.EmailBody !== undefined
  && this.addNotificationTemplateForm.value.EmailBody !== '') {
    const currentValue = this.cursorPositionedField.
       _commandExecutor.savedSelection.
       commonAncestorContainer.textContent;
    const startOffset = this.cursorPositionedField.
       _commandExecutor.savedSelection.startOffset;
    const endOffset = this.cursorPositionedField.
       _commandExecutor.savedSelection.endOffset;
    newValue = [currentValue.slice(0, startOffset), insertField, 
       currentValue.slice(endOffset)].join('');
} 
else {
  newValue = insertField;
}
if (newValue.length <= ValidationConstant.notificationTemplate.
  add.emailBody.maxLength) {                      
  this.addNotificationTemplateForm.controls['EmailBody'].
    markAsDirty({ onlySelf: true });                        

  this.addNotificationTemplateForm.controls['EmailBody'].patchValue(newValue);
}
```

For the above scenario `this.EmailBody._commandExecutor.savedSelection` will return `startOffset` and `endOffset`. And we can use the same to insert specific string/characters in specific position.